# Apps for Office 2013: Cannot load custom properties in an outlook item if it is in a shared calendar

Tags: javascript, outlook-2013, apps-for-office

we are developing an app for outlook using Apps for Office JavaScript API. We need to be able to store properties for each appointment per user, but the appointments may or may not reside in the logged-in user's calendar. they may instead be in a shared calendar that the user has been granted read/write access.

However, when using the [loadCustomPropertiesAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142138.aspx) method of the opened item, it fails if the appointment is from a shared calendar.

We attempted to work around this by using the [roamingSettings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/fp161171.aspx) object, but it appears these properties are not per message (like custom Properties are) but rather GLOBAL to the application, so no matter what message they open it will always have the same properties.

Is there any workaround to this? users want to be able to utilize the compose app but need to be able to use it with shared calendars.

Comment: To clarify, you need to store custom properties in shared calendars that are user specific? That is, user A cannot see user B's custom props?

Comment: thank you for your reply. it is not a requirement in this case that User A cannot see the properties for User B, since the properties in this particular case would be identical (the properties are associated with the item, not the user, and would be the same for each). My understanding is that the custom properties are unique per user, which would also be fine. the problem is that they don't appear to be useable unless the appointment is in the primary calendar of the logged in user only...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cross [posted this on the Apps for Office 2013 forum on MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/3f7d11f9-2056-4d15-bb40-c053688f9219/loading-custom-properties-in-an-appointment-from-a-shared-calendar?forum=appsforoffice) and it appears that the current version of the API (1.1) simply does not support custom fields for shared calendars, and there is no known workaround.

If you require this feature yourself, please upvote this request in UserVoice for the feature: http://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/suggestions/8013672-appointment-api-does-not-support-multiple-shared

Answer (score 1):

You could use the roamingSettings object, but store the information keyed to the message. So, suppose you need to store data on 5 different messages, you'd store 5 items in roamingSettings, with each item named so you can find it later while looking at the message in the shared calendar.

Comment: I thought about this approach but unfortunately we'd be dealing with potentially thousands of messages, it just wouldn't scale. it appears this is simply a limitation of the API and there is no current workaround, i'll update this Q with an answer stating so and linking to a uservoice to requset the required feature. thanks for your reply!